# Move DOM elements off screen without increasing body width

Tags: css, animation

I am using bootstrap 3 for my web application, and I am running into and issue.

My navbar is wrapped in a container div,
my main content is wrapped in a container div adjacent to the navbar like so:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        //Navbar stuff
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        //Navbar stuff
    </div>
</body>
```

I have an animation on the body content that slides all of the content off of the screen while transitioning to a new screen. to do so I animate the left attribute to be off screen.

From what I can gather, this is causing the body width to expand beyond it's normal size, and this is causing my navbar to be affected by the position of content during the animation.

Is there a way to implement a sliding animation without increasing the width of the body, so that my navbar does not get moved during the animation?

EDIT:

To clarify how I am doing the animations, I am using CSS3 animation keyframes, and applying the class to the element I am sliding of screen. Here is the LESS that is doing this

```
@animation-duration: 300ms;
@animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
@animation-fill-mode:forwards;
@animation-iteration-count: 1;
.slide-in-right{
    animation-name: slideInRight;
    animation-duration:@animation-duration;
    animation-timing-function: @animation-timing-function;
    animation-fill-mode: @animation-fill-mode;
    animation-iteration-count: @animation-iteration-count;
}
.slide-out-right{
    animation-name: slideInRight;
    animation-duration:@animation-duration;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-timing-function: @animation-timing-function;
    animation-fill-mode: @animation-fill-mode;
    animation-iteration-count: @animation-iteration-count;
}
.slide-in-left{
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
    animation-duration: 300ms;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;

}
.slide-out-left{
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-duration:@animation-duration;
    animation-timing-function: @animation-timing-function;
    animation-fill-mode: @animation-fill-mode;
    animation-iteration-count: @animation-iteration-count;
}

@keyframes slideInRight{
    0%{
        position:relative;
        left: 150%;
    }
    100%{
        position:relative;
        left:0%;
    }
}

@keyframes slideInLeft{
    0%{
        position:relative;
        left: -150%;
    }
    100%{
        position:relative;
        left:0%;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide the code you have currently that is moving the content off screen and affecting body width.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `transform: translateX(-100%);` (where `-100%` is whatever you have to do to move it off screen), it shouldn't affect body width.

Also, using `position: absolute; left: -100%;` (again, `-100%` is whatever you have to do to move the element off screen), the body width shouldn't be affected, either.